# Need to know how can i store a Map in android persistent memory from native HAL

Tags: android, c++, hal

I am working on creating a service inside android. The native layer is storing some values which i require even after the system power cycle. I want to know which part of the memory i can access from the native layer to keep my data safe for use later. A code snippet would be highly appreciated.

Comment: _"...which i require even after the system power cycle..."_: you will need to store your data (in some format) in persistent storage and reload it later.

Answer (score 0):

The `/data` partition should be the only one that is writable in Android. You can use basic posix commands to write to `/data/vendor`.

```cpp
int fd = open("/data/vendor/myfile", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT);
write(fd, "data", 4);
close(fd);
```

**Note:** Please apply proper error handling :)

---

An alternative to writing files is using system properties with a `persist.` prefix.

```cpp
#include <android-base/properties.h>

// ...

android::base::SetProperty("persist.myprop", "my value as a string");
// ...
std::string val = android::base::GetProperty("persist.myprop");
```

The above example uses the [original system properties interface](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/refs/heads/pie-release/base/include/android-base/properties.h), with Android 10 system properties became [more powerful](https://source.android.com/devices/architecture/sysprops-apis.).

Comment: I tried writing to /data/vendor from surface flinger, but it has no permission to write there

Comment: Do you get an avc error message in logcat?

Comment: errno is EACCES (permission denied)

Comment: BTW, was successful with your system property method :)